# Responsive navigation not appear in Safari, Android Chrome, and iOS Safari

Tags: android, ios, css, safari

Works fine in Chrome & Firefox ( both PC and Mac ).

basically it's a slidetoggle and that works, but based one the display:block of the elements it is basically transparent in the browsers cited above [meaning you can click and it will take you to it's linked tag].

The site has one breaking point at > 1230px, then it basically gets responsively smaller until you hit < 700px where the navigation will change.

Please help if you can and have experience working with browser sited above

Look at the code here: http://www.testing.sixstarproductions.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. I have a fixed header with a fixed nav inside it, what I need to do was make overflow:visible on the header element.

It worked on Chrome and Firefox beforehand but not Safari or mobile browsers, so in case anyone came to this issue now you have an answer.

Thanks for looking